# change background in a metrostyle app using c # xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I created a metrostyle ap using c#, when I started I choose the grid option, but I need to change the background of my app, to an image or another color.

I followed the Microsoft tutorial [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx)

I put in common/standarStyle next code but doesn't work, I know that is something very simple but don´t works for me.

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush}">
// Add this brush to the resource dictionary in App.xaml.
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowsBlogBackgroundBrush" Color="#FF0A2562"/>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a stupid comment, but shouldn't your `SolidColourBrush` come before your reference to it within your `Grid` element?

Comment: Oh, +1'd coulton then noticed "// Add this brush to the resource dictionary in App.xaml." sorry.

Comment: is ok @Coulton as I said, I followed the microsoft's tutorial,  I put the first line in standardStyle file and the 2 in App.xml, but don't works, I have to send my app today!!! and I just need to make that change :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush
            Color="#FF0A2562" />
    </Grid.Background>

    ...
</Grid>
```

If it does not help then perhaps your Grid is not visible - its content might have a different color and fill the grid completely - then you would not see its color.

Comment: thanks for your help, I think you are right because I can't change the color, this is the first time that I work with metrostyle, at the beginning of my project I choosed the option "grid" and I choosed black and grey color, I thought that was that easy to change again but I have no options, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Set Background property of grid to

```
  grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(1,10,37,98));
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest way is: use the program blender, (wich comes in the package for developers in microsoft site) open a new project (and open as new our project made in vs) left button, it opens the tool designer, and you can choose the solid color brush or gradient brush option.

Comment: the program is Blend, not to be confused with Blender (a 3d model designer)